# VSCode syntax highlight for coffeescript appears to be incomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code, coffeescript, syntax-highlighting

I just started using coffeescript, and I use my preferred editor VSCode in its version 1.45.0 (latest as of today) and its standard theme.

When I write coffeescript code in a file with the file extension .coffee, I get some syntax highlight but it appears to be incomplete.

The code:

```
name = "Someone"
person = true
age = 19
yell = (number) -> 
    console.log name, "is now", number
yell(age) if person and name isnt "Scott"
```

And how it looks like:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fV1g.png)

I find it weird that variables appear differently on second usage, however that might be normal syntax highlight for coffeescript. However, words like "is" or "isnt" aren't recognised.

What I tried:

- deactivating all extensions
- using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yorkxin.coffeescript-support
- I searched on Stackoverflow and Google and Github and did not find anything that seemed helpful

Did anyone find a way or does anyone have ideas on how to to write coffeescript in VSCode with more meaningful syntax highlight?